# Button in Form Element Is Not Positioned Correctly

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner and trying to position a `button` that sits inside a `form` element on the bottom right of a container, but not able to do so. Please advise. Thank you.

Whether using the `float:right;` or `position: absolute;`, the button is being taken out of the container(from my understanding from the dev tool on Google Chrome).

[image: meme generator page]

HTML markup:

```html
<section class="form-container">
    <h1>Meme Generator</h1>
    <p>Fill out the form to start creating memes!</p>
    <form action="#">
        <label for="img-url"
          >Image URL
          <input type="text" id="img-url" />
        </label>
        <label for="top-txt"
          >Text On Top
          <input type="text" id="top-txt" />
        </label>
        <label for="bottom-txt">Text On Bottom
          <input type="text" id="bottom-txt" />
        </label>
        <button>Add Meme</button>
    </form>
</section>
```

CSS:

```css
/* Reset */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Set core body defaults */
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }

/* Input buttons don't inherit font property */
/* Inherit fonts for inputs and buttons */
input, button {
  font: inherit;
}

/* VARIABLES */

:root {
    --spacing: 1rem;
}

/* GENERAL STYLE - MOBILE FIRST*/

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', Courier, monospace;
}

.form-container {
    padding: var(--spacing);
    background-color: rgba(245, 221, 194, 0.75);
    min-width: 100%;
}

.form-container h1,
.form-container p {
    text-align: center;
}

form {
    position: relative;
}

form label {
    display: block;
    margin-top: var(--spacing);
}

label input {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
}

form button {
    margin-top: var(--spacing);
    padding-left: var(--spacing);
    padding-right: var(--spacing);

    /* when setting absolute, it's being taken out of the .form-container */
    /* position: absolute; */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the form to `display: flex` and align vertically using `flex-direction: column`, then set the button to `align-self: flex-end` to be moved at the right side of the flex container.

Here are the changes:

```css
form {
  position: relative;
  display: flex; /* <= set form display to flexbox */
  flex-direction: column; /* <= set direction to vertical */
}
form button {
  margin-top: var(--spacing);
  padding-left: var(--spacing);
  padding-right: var(--spacing);
  align-self: flex-end; /* <= set the alignment of the button to flex-end so that it is moved at the end of the last row */
}
```

Now, to understand why `float` and `position: aboslute` do not have the effect that you would expect, let's take a look a what these two actually do:

- **float:** *"The element is removed from the normal flow of the page"* [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)
- **position: absolute** *"The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout."* [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute)

```css
/* Reset */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Set core body defaults */
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }

/* Input buttons don't inherit font property */
/* Inherit fonts for inputs and buttons */
input, button {
  font: inherit;
}

/* VARIABLES */

:root {
    --spacing: 1rem;
}

/* GENERAL STYLE - MOBILE FIRST*/

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', Courier, monospace;
}

.form-container {
    padding: var(--spacing);
    background-color: rgba(245, 221, 194, 0.75);
    min-width: 100%;
}

.form-container h1,
.form-container p {
    text-align: center;
}

form {
    position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

form label {
    display: block;
    margin-top: var(--spacing);
}

label input {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
}

form button {
    margin-top: var(--spacing);
    padding-left: var(--spacing);
    padding-right: var(--spacing);
    align-self: flex-end;
    /* when setting absolute, it's being taken out of the .form-container */
    /* position: absolute; */
}
```

```html
<section class="form-container">
      <h1>Meme Generator</h1>
      <p>Fill out the form to start creating memes!</p>
      <form action="#">
        <label for="img-url"
          >Image URL
          <input type="text" id="img-url" />
        </label>
        <label for="top-txt"
          >Text On Top
          <input type="text" id="top-txt" />
        </label>
        <label for="bottom-txt"
          >Text On Bottom
          <input type="text" id="bottom-txt" />
        </label>
        <button>Add Meme</button>
      </form>
    </section>
```

---

**Solution #2:** Clearing the float:

You can `clear` the float by appending an empty div that has the `clear` property set to `both` which clears the "floating" and produces the result that you are looking for. Check this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) to understand how `clear` works.

```css
/* Reset */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Set core body defaults */
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }

/* Input buttons don't inherit font property */
/* Inherit fonts for inputs and buttons */
input, button {
  font: inherit;
}

/* VARIABLES */

:root {
    --spacing: 1rem;
}

/* GENERAL STYLE - MOBILE FIRST*/

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', Courier, monospace;
}

.form-container {
    padding: var(--spacing);
    background-color: rgba(245, 221, 194, 0.75);
    min-width: 100%;
}

.form-container h1,
.form-container p {
    text-align: center;
}

form {
    position: relative;
}

form label {
    display: block;
    margin-top: var(--spacing);
}

label input {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
}

form button {
    margin-top: var(--spacing);
    padding-left: var(--spacing);
    padding-right: var(--spacing);
  float: right;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<section class="form-container">
      <h1>Meme Generator</h1>
      <p>Fill out the form to start creating memes!</p>
      <form action="#">
        <label for="img-url"
          >Image URL
          <input type="text" id="img-url" />
        </label>
        <label for="top-txt"
          >Text On Top
          <input type="text" id="top-txt" />
        </label>
        <label for="bottom-txt"
          >Text On Bottom
          <input type="text" id="bottom-txt" />
        </label>
        <button>Add Meme</button>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </form>
    </section>
```

---

**Solution #3:** Using `position:absolute`

You can use `position: absolute` on the button, but you will have to tweak the code a bit. You will need to (1) remove the `position:relative` from the form and move it to the `form-container`, add a bit of padding at the bottom and they play around with the `bottom` and `right` values of the absolutely positioned button to get the layout that you want:

```css
/* Reset */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Set core body defaults */
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }

/* Input buttons don't inherit font property */
/* Inherit fonts for inputs and buttons */
input, button {
  font: inherit;
}

/* VARIABLES */

:root {
    --spacing: 1rem;
}

/* GENERAL STYLE - MOBILE FIRST*/

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', Courier, monospace;
}

.form-container {
    padding: var(--spacing);
    background-color: rgba(245, 221, 194, 0.75);
    min-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 4rem;
}

.form-container h1,
.form-container p {
    text-align: center;
}

form label {
    display: block;
    margin-top: var(--spacing);
}

label input {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
}

form button {
    margin-top: var(--spacing);
    padding-left: var(--spacing);
    padding-right: var(--spacing);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="form-container">
      <h1>Meme Generator</h1>
      <p>Fill out the form to start creating memes!</p>
      <form action="#">
        <label for="img-url"
          >Image URL
          <input type="text" id="img-url" />
        </label>
        <label for="top-txt"
          >Text On Top
          <input type="text" id="top-txt" />
        </label>
        <label for="bottom-txt"
          >Text On Bottom
          <input type="text" id="bottom-txt" />
        </label>
        <button>Add Meme</button>
      </form>
    </section>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution. Do you know why my code is not working? Would love to find out the problem as well. Thanks.

Comment: Sure! I've updated the answer with some more details. You should read both MDN pages to better understand the effect that each of these CSS properties has on the layout and the document flow. Roughly, they both remove the element from the normal flow and do not affect the container element's size.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I understand that `position: absolute;` will remove the element from the normal flow. That is why I put `position: relative;` in the `button`'s parent element which is the `form` element. It confused me when the `button` was not positioned correctly. Do you know why?

Comment: When the button gets removed from the normal flow, it will not "push" the parent element downwards, therefore it will not create extra space inside the form. Putting `position: relative` to the form positions the button absolutely with reference to the form but the fact remains the same. Outside of the normal flow, the form will not make space for this absolutely position child element.

Answer (score 0):

You could also set the height of the form container to lets say 50% and the form button float to left.

This is the code;

```css
/* Reset */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Set core body defaults */
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }

/* Input buttons don't inherit font property */
/* Inherit fonts for inputs and buttons */
input, button {
  font: inherit;
}

/* VARIABLES */

:root {
    --spacing: 1rem;
}

/* GENERAL STYLE - MOBILE FIRST*/

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', Courier, monospace;
}

.form-container {
    padding: var(--spacing);
    background-color: rgba(245, 221, 194, 0.75);
    min-width: 100%;
    height:50%;
}

.form-container h1,
.form-container p {
    text-align: center;
}

form {
    position: relative;
}

form label {
    display: block;
    margin-top: var(--spacing);
}

label input {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
}

form button {
    margin-top: var(--spacing);
    padding-left: var(--spacing);
    padding-right: var(--spacing);
    float:right;

    /* when setting absolute, it's being taken out of the .form-container */
    /* position: absolute; */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
I have added **float: right** and **form-container::after**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Set core body defaults */
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }

/* Input buttons don't inherit font property */
/* Inherit fonts for inputs and buttons */
input, button {
  font: inherit;
}

/* VARIABLES */

:root {
    --spacing: 1rem;
}

/* GENERAL STYLE - MOBILE FIRST*/

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', Courier, monospace;
}

.form-container {
    padding: var(--spacing);
    background-color: rgba(245, 221, 194, 0.75);
    min-width: 100%;
}

.form-container h1,
.form-container p {
    text-align: center;
}

form {
    position: relative;
}

form label {
    display: block;
    margin-top: var(--spacing);
}

label input {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
}

form button {
    margin-top: var(--spacing);
    padding-left: var(--spacing);
    padding-right: var(--spacing);
    float: right;
}

.form-container::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <section class="form-container">
        <h1>Meme Generator</h1>
        <p>Fill out the form to start creating memes!</p>
        <form action="#">
            <label for="img-url"
              >Image URL
              <input type="text" id="img-url" />
            </label>
            <label for="top-txt"
              >Text On Top
              <input type="text" id="top-txt" />
            </label>
            <label for="bottom-txt">Text On Bottom
                <input type="text" id="bottom-txt" />
            </label>
            <button>Add Meme</button>
        </form>
    </section>
    
</body>
</html>
```